# The file is in the same directory but cannot be imported

Tags: python-3.x

The python version I am using is 3.8.2
I searched a lot and most of the solutions are to use `sys.path.append()`
But it didn't solve the problem for me, if I use `from . import players`
it will say
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

if i use `import players` it will say
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'players'`

The code I used to fix this:

1. `sys.path.append(".")`
2. `sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + "\\players.py")`
3. `sys.path.append(os.getcwd())`

still can't fix this,It's worth mentioning that at some point `sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + "\\players.py")` can run

Comment: From where are you starting the program that does these imports?

Comment: What I meant is *from which directory*.

Comment: @RolandSmith All scripts are in one folder, it seems that there is only a problem with importing `players.py`, other scripts are imported without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of the file is actually `players.py`.
And not for example  `players.py`, `players .py` (note the spaces).
Also check for all other "invisible" Unicode characters that would not necessarily show up.

And make sure that there is no directory `players` as well.

Comment: I can be sure there is no problem with my filename and path, I checked.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the file completely so I couldn't test it, but I ran into this problem again, it's an import order problem, I tried to import `attributes.py` first and then `content.py`, there was a problem Check, can't find `attributes.py` , the problem is solved when their import order is swapped, I can't understand why, but if you encounter such problems please try once (other files are not imported)